# How can I get Plank and Wingpanel on both monitors without Mirroring Screens

Tags: plank, wingpanel

I would like to get Plank and Wingpanel on both screens of my dual monitor set up without mirroring my screens. How can I do this?

Comment: How do you expect it to look like? I'm assuming you're thinking of "duplicating" them to be displayed on both monitors?

Comment: Something like that, yeah

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Plank (Buttom Dockbar):

It's really easy to mirror plank to more than one screen.

- Make sure that `dconf Editor` is installed:
  `sudo apt-get install dconf-tools`.
- Convert existing `dock` into `dock1` and add `dock2`, `dock3 ..` :
  `cd ~/.config/plank & mkdir dock2 dock3 ..`
- Copy `settings` files:
  `cp dock1/settings dock2/ & cp dock1/settings dock3/ ..`
- Link icons form `dock1` to `dock2,..`:
  `ln -s dock1/launchers/ dock2/launchers & ln -s dock1/launchers/ dock3/launchers ..`
- Identify monitor IDs:
  `xrandr | grep " connected"`
  Output: `eDP1` `DP1-2` `DP1-3` `..`
- Set monitor for dockX:
  `sudo nano dockX/settings`
  `Monitor=` `eDP1`/`DP1-2`/`DP1-3`/`..`
- Apply settings to pantheon:
  `Apps -> dconf Editor` and `org -> pantheon -> cerbere`
  Replace `'..plank..'` with `'plank -n dock1 & plank -n dock2 & plank -n dock3 ..'`

**Sources:**
[Fun tip: Have plank run on multiple monitors!](https://www.reddit.com/r/elementaryos/comments/21nfw9/fun_tip_have_plank_run_on_multiple_monitors)
[Dual docks in elementary OS](https://heathpaddock.com/?p=761)

### Wingpanel (Top Systembar):

**Update:** There is a ported version of autohide available here, [WingPanel » Add optional hide mode](https://www.bountysource.com/issues/955498-add-optional-hide-mode).

> **[Bug #1237228](https://bugs.launchpad.net/wingpanel/+bug/1237228)**
>
> It should be an option to have wingpanel placed on multiple monitors. >
> Perhaps the monitor number could be specified through a command line argument so that any combination of instances/monitors could be achieved.

**Other customizations:**

> **[How to install wingpanel-slim or super-wingpanel on elementary 0.3 Freya (amd64)?](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/912/1193)**
>
> Both wingpanel-slim and super-wingpanel were developed and maintained by a developer on Launchpad called ~heathbar. Unfortunately, it looks like he abandonded both projects and did not update them to work with Freya (last change to wingpanel-slim was 2013-11-19, last change to super-wingpanel was 2014-03-04).
>
> Therefore, sadly, there is (currently) no way to use one of those on Freya. Maybe development will be resumed by someone else, but at this very moment, it's simply not possible.

> **[(Freya) Make Wing-panel Clear](https://www.reddit.com/r/elementaryos/comments/30alrd/freya_make_wingpanel_clear/)**
>
> Install dconf editor (`sudo apt-get install dconf-editor`)
>
> In dconf-editor: `org>pantheon>desktop>wingpanel`
>
> Unselect `auto-adjust-alpha` and set `background-alpha` to `0.0`. Done :)

Comment: "It's really easy"  ahahahahhaha Programmers...

Answer (score 6):

Heath Paddock has since release an application called [multiplank](https://heathpaddock.com/?p=854) that does the configuration automatically.

To install the app from his PPA:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:heathbar/multiplank
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install multiplank
```

Once installed, enable multiplank by issuing the following command:

`multiplank -e`

And to disable:

`multiplank -d`

Comment: Does not works with latest versions of Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

for an easy way and for a full discription to how create multiple docks in plank check this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xNIWq4hgw78&t=14s

Comment: We don't have time to watch a video, Ilyes

Comment: it's just 4 minutes

Answer (score -2):

I don't know about Wingpanel, but Heath Paddock wrote this tutorial for Plank. https://heathpaddock.com/?p=761

Comment: Downvoting, [answers should contain more info than only links.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259)