# How to install wingpanel-slim or super-wingpanel on elementary 0.3 Freya (amd64)?

Tags: release-freya, wingpanel

I want to tweak the top panel of the window,and I founded two kits named "wingpanel-slim" and "super-wingpanel" can do what I want to (auto hide and ...)

I tried to install the from several PPA but no one success.

Comment: It will take some time, but there is a bug report for WingPanel to get autohide: [Bug #1079575 "Add optional hide mode"](https://bugs.launchpad.net/wingpanel/+bug/1079575)

Answer (score 14):

Both `wingpanel-slim` and `super-wingpanel` were developed and maintained by a developer on Launchpad called [~heathbar](https://launchpad.net/~heathbar). Unfortunately, it looks like he abandonded both projects and did not update them to work with Freya (last change to `wingpanel-slim` was [2013-11-19](https://code.launchpad.net/~heathbar/wingpanel/wingpanel-slim), last change to `super-wingpanel` was [2014-03-04](https://code.launchpad.net/super-wingpanel)).

Therefore, sadly, there is (currently) no way to use one of those on Freya. Maybe development will be resumed by someone else, but at this very moment, it's simply not possible.

Comment: I believe Heath Paddock said (on Google+) that due to the new headerbars which are omnipresent in Freya a slim panel would make no sense, so he deliberately ceased development.

Comment: Is there any way to auto hide or customize the top banner？

Comment: @AaronZhang if you're looking for customization options for `wingpanel`, please open another question. That's not really related to your current question and follow-up questions as comments are generally discouraged :)

Comment: Not currently, but there is a [bug bounty](https://www.bountysource.com/issues/955498-add-optional-hide-mode) currently worth $80 that might be what you're looking for.

Comment: @embik♦ Thanks your suggest. I opened the new question in here  http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/916/is-there-any-way-to-auto-hide-or-customize-the-top-panel-elementary-0-3-freya-a