# Is there any way to auto hide or customize the top panel? (Freya)

Tags: wingpanel

I want to auto hide or change the position of the top panel，How can I do it?
Install some things or change some settings?

Answer (score 8):

Right now, no way. There is a bug report for [wingpanel auto hide](https://www.bountysource.com/issues/955498-add-optional-hide-mode).

The position of the panel is not configurable.

Comment: I can see that Keith Baley, even if he has not released his wingpanel version, has posted a video that shows it working pretty good; is it safe to compile and install it? If at a certain point you decide to remove it and go back to standard Freya's wingpanel, is still possible?

Comment: What you mean with safe? If you overwrite system stuff you can always break your system. So you should know what you are doing. If you do it right (install in /usr) you can revert back with apt-get install wingpanel --reinstall

Comment: Ok, that's wath I meant; since I've cloned the repository and I've seen install instructions, but no info about going back to previous version

Comment: See The answer below.

Answer (score 1):

What You want has been implemented by a person.

Here is its [LaunchPad Code](https://code.launchpad.net/~kbailey4444/wingpanel/dodge-maximize)

Follow This [Discussion](https://www.bountysource.com/issues/955498-add-optional-hide-mode) About its Development.
Refer [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y08u_bcJL-U) to see it in action.

Answer (score 1):

I ported the above code from launchpad to a new [git branch](https://github.com/quequotion/wingpanel) for Juno+; this version of wingpanel requires gtk3 version 3.22 or higher!

I'd like to get this code adopted upstream, but it's a [tough sell](https://github.com/elementary/wingpanel/pull/93).