# Show a name of the current application on wingpanel like in OS X

Tags: release-freya, wingpanel

Is there a way to see a name of the current application on wingpanel? I know that is possible to launch applications on Freya and see "global menu" on wingpanel, but I didn't found any wingpanel's fork that shows name of the application.

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't any version of wingpanel available that suits your request. In fact, there is no active fork of wingpanel anymore. You can find a bit more information [here](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/910/how-to-install-wingpanel-slim-or-super-wingpanel-on-elementary-0-3-freya-amd64/912#912). Both popular wingpanel forks are abandoned.