# How to get Wingpanel/Plank onto second monitor?

Tags: release-hera, wingpanel, plank

Trying to figure out how to have my secondary monitor include both wingpanel/plank.

I tried this solution but no go: https://heathpaddock.com/2015/11/12/multi-planking-in-elementary-os/ - this is what happens:

```
Hit:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/teejee2008/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease

Err:17 http://ppa.launchpad.net/heathbar/multiplank/ubuntu bionic Release

404 Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8008::19 80]

Reading package lists... Done

E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/heathbar/multiplank/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.

N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.

N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.

usr@usr:~$ sudo apt-get install multiplank

Reading package lists... Done

Building dependency tree

Reading state information... Done

E: Unable to locate package multiplank
```

I have also tried: [How can I get Plank and Wingpanel on both monitors without Mirroring Screens](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/876/how-can-i-get-plank-and-wingpanel-on-both-monitors-without-mirroring-screens)

So far, I have only been able to use a tool called AutoPlank which isnt perfect and laggy - but it at least moves the dock over to the current monitor im working in when needed.

Anyone find a way to do this? Running: elementary OS 5.1.7 Hera x86_64